# PHP & Wordpress Memory limit not increasing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have set 1024M in `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I have set it in `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>
```

I have set it in `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '1024M');
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

But I still get the following error on a plugin page in my Wordpress admin area:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in /home/eroticnaughtines/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4212
```

And yes, all the files are in the root directory of my Wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime host controls these files and even if you update them they will never get executed specially in some cases they revert back to original so best is to contact your hosting and ask them to either give you server control or increase memory limit on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your web service? It's the problem.

another reason may be your theme back-end problem. 
Update your WORDPRESS and theme version.

Answer (score 0):

To check if you successfully increased the memory_limit in php.ini file, you may create phpinfo() function to view your php settings. Please refer to this link https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/view-php-settings

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the link may solve the answer, it's better to include the relevant information in the answer in the event the link no longer works.